# (DirectX) Generating a rotation matrix to match a vector

Tags: c++, matrix, directx, directx-9

How can I take a vector and generate a matrix that will rotate a mesh to face along that vector?

Specifics:

I want the model for my player to rotate to face the direction that the camera is looking.  Right now, it always points in the direction it started in, and turning just makes the camera look at the player's side.

I have experimented with D3DXMatrixYawPitchRoll, with partial success.  However, I noticed some drift in time from perfect alignment, and it had some strange wobbly issues when I tried pitching while yawing.

Answer (score 2):

It will work in almost exactly the same way as this answer I've posted:

[Rotate a sphere so that its pole heads towards the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237873/rotate-a-sphere-so-that-its-pole-heads-towards-the-camera/4237921#4237921)

The main change is that instead of "camera position" - "object origin" you do "object origin" - "camera position".

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like it will do nicely.  Also, I've now learned to use wider search terms.

Comment: @Dahud: Its always hard to find existing answers as the question asked, while it may be similar to yours, is often asked in a totally different way.  Feel free to accept my answer if it solves your problem though :)

Comment: Huh.  It didn't work.  I tried dropping it straight in, and the player vanished.  Might it have something to do with the fact that I'm pitching while yawing?  I might have to make a video of the odd behaviour.

Comment: @Dahud: It would be handy to see some code.  I can ee if I can spot what you are doing wrong from that.  Are you remembering to translate the model to the correct place after the rotation?  The rotations MUST happen about the mesh's local origin.  So you may need to translate it to the origin, perform the rotation as described and then translate it BACK to its position.

Comment: Sorry for the latency, I didn't get the notification till now. I just now rephrased my question here, with a video of the bug in action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699172/strange-behavior-with-rotation-matrices